# Bootstrap колонка фиксированный

Tags: css, bootstrap

На bootstrap-e работает. Фиксирует шапку таблицы. Теперь не могу сделать фиксированным первую колонку, нумерацию.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
thead,
tbody,
tr,
td,
th {
  display: block;
}
tr:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
thead th {
  height: 30px;
  /*text-align: left;*/
}
tbody {
  height: 120px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
thead {
  /* fallback */
}
tbody td,
thead th {
  width: 19.2%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">

  <table class="table table-striped responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>№</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Year</th>


      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell" id="fix">1</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell" id="fix">2</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell" id="fix">3</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell" id="fix">4</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


</div>
```

Make
        Model
        Color
        Year
        Year


    
    
    
    
        1
        Escort
        Blue
        2000
        2000

    
    
        2
        Escort
        Blue
        2000
        2000

    
            
        3
        Escort
        Blue
        2000
        2000
         
     
        4
        Escort
        Blue
        2000
        2000

Comment: @Etik что скажешь?

Answer (score 1):

```
tbody tr td:first-child,
thead tr th:first-child
{
    width: 50px !important;
}
```

Comment: Форматируйте код с помощью отступов в 4 пробела, также вы можете выделить отрывок кода в сообщении и нажать сочетание Ctrl+K, чтобы добавить или удалить отступ.